# PowerShell 7.0.2 cannot find DisplaySwitch.exe

Tags: powershell

Within a Powershell 7.0.2 session with administrator privileges, I've found that I can't list or call `C:\Windows\System32\DisplaySwitch.exe`.

I can call that application just fine from `cmd.exe` and `powershell.exe` (aka "Windows PowerShell"), but oddly enough it can't even be listed by `pwsh.exe` (the new PowerShell).

Things I've tried so far:

`PS> DisplaySwitch`
Returns `DisplaySwitch: The term 'DisplaySwitch' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.`

Or `PS> ls C:\Windows\System32\Display*.exe`, which returns nothing.

The same two commands above on the classic Windows Powershell (v5.1) work as expected. I.e., it opens the Display Switch tool and lists the `DisplaySwitch.exe` path, respectively.

Comment: Did you perhaps install the 32-bit version of PowerShell 7?

Comment: Cheers. That was it. After installing the x64 version, it was able to list the file.